# Checking cart items for a product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

In woocommerce, I'm trying to check in cart items for a particular product category using:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'fs_check_category_in_cart');
function fs_check_category_in_cart() {
    // Set $cat_in_cart to false
    $cat_in_cart = false;
    // Loop through all products in the Cart        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        echo '<pre>',print_r($product),'</pre>';
        // If Cart has category "download", set $cat_in_cart to true
        if ( has_term( 'downloads', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Do something if category "download" is in the Cart      
    if ( $cat_in_cart ) {

        // For example, print a notice
        wc_print_notice( 'Category Downloads is in the Cart!', 'notice' );
        // Or maybe run your own function...
        // ..........
    }
}
```

Ive been unable to achieve it. On further inspection when I `print_r( $product )`
the end of the array look like:

```
            [current_class_name:WC_Data_Store:private] => WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT
            [object_type:WC_Data_Store:private] => product-simple
    )

    [meta_data:protected] => 
)
1
```

This 1 at the end of the array is attaching its self to any variable I try and reference. So I get

```
downloads1
```

If anyone knows where this number maybe coming from its been stressing me out!

Just for the record also doing `print_r( $woocommerce )` has the 1 at the end of the array.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is due to the `echo '<pre>',print_r($product),'</pre>';` construct. You either want `echo '<pre>',print_r($product, true),'</pre>';` to make print_r _return_ a string instead of outputting it directly, or you want to use separate statements, `echo '<pre>'; print_r($product); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Try getting the product ID like this $cart_item['product_id'] not $cart_item['data']

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check product categories **in cart items using WordPress [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function, you need to use `$cart_item['product_id']`** instead to handle checking product categories in product variations too.

This way it check in the parent variable product for the product category as **product variation type doesn't handle any custom taxonomy**. So now it will work for all cases.

So your revisited code will be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_product_category_in_cart');
function check_product_category_in_cart() {
    // HERE set your product categories in the array (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $categories = array('downloads');
    $found      = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items      
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // If product categories is found
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; // Set to true
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }

    // If any defined product category is found, we display a notice
    if ( $found ) {
        wc_print_notice( __('Product Category "Downloads" is in Cart items!'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Ah you hero! Thank you very much!

Just to summarise, the number 1 was printing because I was incorrectly echoing the array?